# Issue with ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to create a list from an array of `Request` objects.

I have defined a custom view `RequestRow` to display a `Request`.

The following works to display a list of requests…

```
struct RequestsView : View {

    let requests: [Request]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<requests.count) { i in
                RequestRow(request: self.requests[i])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the following won't compile…

```
struct RequestsView : View {

    let requests: [Request]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(requests) { request in
                RequestRow(request: request)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> `Cannot convert value of type '(Request) -> RequestRow' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'`

Any thoughts as to what the issue might be?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OK, I soon figured out the answer. Per the Apple's docs, the array elements must be `Identifiable`, so this works…

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(requests, id: \.self) { request in
            RequestRow(request: request)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure I won't be the last person to have this problem, so I'll leave this here for future reference.

Comment: Upvoted, but I already worked through this from this link, which may help others also - https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-views-in-a-loop-using-foreach This is an excellent resource, despite SwiftUI being Beta 1! Hope this index helps you with other issues -https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui

Comment: Mush better to use protocol Identifiable on your model. It will make your code more clear

Comment: For XCode 11 Beta 5 and above use: ForEach(requests, id: \.self)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, but in my case `Component` is a Protocol, so it can't be conformed to Identifiable

```
VStack {

       ForEach(components.identified(by: \.uuid)) { value -> UIFactory in
            UIFactory(component: value)
       }
}
```

However, If I try something like this it works fine

```
VStack {

       ForEach(components.identified(by: \.uuid)) { value -> UIFactory in
            Text(value.uuid)
       }
}
```